# JNI for loop has run incurrectly in C

Tags: android, java-native-interface

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
```

This loop was run repeatly by incrementing value of i by 1.
I have develop in Android JNI.
An OpenGL Renderer's onDrawFrame method calls repeatly.
In onDrawFrame, render function in C++ was call.

in a c++ render function. for loop runs 100 times over.

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , "", "%d", i);
}
```

This loop runs incorrectly.

i value has not incremented by 1.
in other case, loop is not run 100 times. some times 90, 98, or 96.....

I don't know reason.

Comment: How did you determine the loop runs incorrectly? You just state your conclusion without explaining how you reached it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot trust that `__android_log_print()` output will be displayed, especially if you are using the logcat window in Eclispe. You can write instead to local file, and then you will for sure see 100 lines in that file after you start the loop.